# Add bootstrap rows and cols via wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, templates, widget

I hope this question isn't deemed as being too general... I'm looking for a way to allow clients to add bootstrap rows and columns and populate them with content via wp-admin. The idea I have in my head is that they'd add a page and would then be presented with the option to add a row, select the number of columns and then fill those with content - possibly using widgets, i haven't thought that far ahead yet to be honest.

I know this is a big one but I know it's possible as I've seen it done before - the trouble is in that case the developer in question basically ripped up half of WordPress and replaced it with an MVC model which, well, let's just say there were issues...

I guess what I'm looking for initially is to be pointed in the right direction - is this something I can achieve using templates or widgets or should I be looking at building a plugin.

Any general (or indeed specific!) ideas to point me in the right direction  and help me on my way would be much appreciated at this point.

Many thanks
Stef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hard option**

You'd possibly be looking at building a Plugin for this which would allow users to change the layouts of pages while using the text editor per page. That in itself is pretty extensive but not impossible. I'm not sure where to point you after this.

**Easy Solution**

Another option is to build your theme in a way that accepts different cols/rows within `<?php the_content(); ?>` call. So.. when a user is creating/editing a page/post/custompost they could set the `cols`themselves via the page editor.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Advanced Custom Fields is a plugin that allows you to create a flexible content field for the Wordpress admin side. It takes a fair amount of logic on the template, but if you want to allow this possibility, that's what I recommend. They do have a license fee for their "PRO" features which is what you would need, but it's a one time fee with unlimited updates.

Their documentation is great, and they also have great support forums as well. Specifically check out the Flexible Content field.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for both your input, was thinking of ACF as an option, I think it's about making the backend as friendly as possible to those who don't have a lot of technical expertise. I accepted the first as an answer because it points me in the right direction in terms of coding but both were useful, so cheers again ;-)